# Jordan curves in compact subset in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Always exist a curve in compact and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: What if the compact convex is equal to a single point?

Comment: the curve is constant iguals the point.

Comment: If you allow for constant curves, then *every* nonempty subset of $\mathbb R^3$ contains a curve, and your question is therefore not a very interesting one :-) (But in that case one can wonder why you have the name «Jordan» in the title of your question...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the set contains three non-collinear points, then it contains a triangle, and the answer is clearly yes.

If the set does not contain three non-collinear points then it is a closed segment or a point. If you are looking for closed simple curves, then in this case the answer is no.